# Set textarea selection in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, textarea, range, selection

I'm looking for a way to *set* a selection in a textarea in Internet Explorer. In other browsers, this works just fine:

```
textarea.selectionStart = start;
textarea.selectionEnd = end;
```

In IE, I assume I have to use `createRange` and adjust the selection somehow, but I cannot figure out how.

Extra bonus points for a link to a proper documentation about `createRange` and associated methods, MSDN isn't helping out much.

Comment: +1 - I looked at this.  I can't remember the details (sorry) but it's sticky.  IE was being very unhelpful.  I had to make some kind of compromise in my form design.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<textarea id="lol">
noasdfkvbsdobfbgvobosdobfbgoasopdobfgbooaodfgh
</textarea>

<script>
var range = document.getElementById('lol').createTextRange();
range.collapse(true);
range.moveStart('character', 5);
range.moveEnd('character', 10);
range.select();
</script>
```

Useful links:

- http://help.dottoro.com/ljlwflaq.php
- http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/ncz/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

moveStart() at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536623%28VS.85%29.aspx

moveEnd() at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536620%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Excellent, it actually works. `moveEnd` apparently moves the selection relative to the start position, so it behaves differently than `.selectionEnd`. Great links, thanks! Hopefully the bonus points I promised will come through other people upvoting :)

Answer (score 17):

Try with

```
function select(e, start, end){
     e.focus();
     if(e.setSelectionRange)
        e.setSelectionRange(start, end);
     else if(e.createTextRange) {
        e = e.createTextRange();
        e.collapse(true);
        e.moveEnd('character', end);
        e.moveStart('character', start);
        e.select();
     }
}
select(document.getElementById('textarea_id'), 5, 10);
```

Comment: +1 for creating a browser-aware function and moving the end first so no arithmetic isn't required. It's a shame I can't accept two answers as correct, watain was first and provided links :)

Comment: Thank you. I know, watain was first and provided some links to documentation, so his answer is the one to be marked as accepted.

Comment: The re-use of variable name 'e' threw me off, but I think I see what you are doing there.

Comment: Apparently `setSelectionRange()` is supported in IE9+: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange

Answer (score 6):

As already commented the move methods see the line separators as one character (`\n`) instead of two (`\r\n`). I have adjusted the routine to compensate for that:

```
function select(el, start, end) {
    el.focus();

    if (el.setSelectionRange) { 
        el.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } 
    else { 
        if(el.createTextRange) { 
            var normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            start -= normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;
            end -= normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;

            range=el.createTextRange(); 
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start); 
            range.select();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of line separators, move* methods see them as one character, but they are actually two - \r\n