# How to change a single character color in textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please i need to change color of a single character in textarea using JQuery.

Comment: Add more requirements and please show how far you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the textarea by a content editable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>


div {width:98%;clear: both;font-size: 10pt;max-width:98%;height:250px;min-height:98%; 
      left:10px;right:10px;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #1c578d;bottom:10px;top:10px;color:#1B4A90;overflow:auto;
      display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. A textarea is plain text only. That's why, for example, HTML inside a textarea is rendered literally (except for `</textarea>`).

Comment: [Live under a rock much?](http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/)

Comment: Hax. It is ugly, especially when scrolling, editing or resizing, or just generally doing anything other than looking at the textarea. And if the only point of a textarea is to be looked at, why bother making it a textarea?

Comment: @bzlm: this would be cool if the textarea didn't have to be sized using known values - i.e. it doesn't like `position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;'. That it whacks a bunch of wrapper divs around the box too is annoying. And that the font rendering is nasty.. i mean, http://ace.c9.io/ is neat but overkill if you just want to highlight text! For me, this solution has potential in some corner cases...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but in HTML5 there is the contenteditable attribute. [Here is a link to an example](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable). This does support specific styling.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be to create your own "element". For example, create an empty `div`, and a focus handler which would enable the key press listener - the key press handler would then at the pressed character to the html of the div. If the char is the one (or one of those) you want you'd add a `span` (for example) around it to style it. Of course, you'll have to be able to handle things such as holding down a keyboard key should keep adding the same char, also you'd need to handle deleting via delete, backspace, and selection, etc. A lot of stuff to do just to be able to highlight a char.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change colors, but what you can do is select a particular character (highlight by way of JavaScript.)

See [Highlighting a piece of string in a TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549250/highlighting-a-piece-of-string-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery plugin:
jQuery.colorfy

https://github.com/cheunghy/jquery.colorfy

Demo here: http://cheunghy.github.io/jquery.colorfy/

Answer (score 0):

Change color of @ Username # Hashtag and link with clickable

**Pure Vanilla JavaScript**

```js
const linkGenerator = ( contentElement, baseUrl ) => {
  const elem = document.querySelector(contentElement);
      elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML
        .replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, `<a class='link' href="$1">$1</a>`)
        .replace(/(@[^\s]+)/g, `<a class='username' href='${baseUrl}/$1' title='$1'>$1</a>`)
        .replace(/(#[^\s]+)/g, `<a class='hashtag' href='${baseUrl}/$1'>$1</a>`)
        
  return elem
}

linkGenerator( '#myContent', 'https://www.any-domain.net');

linkGenerator( '#myContent2', 'https://www.any-domain.org');
```

```css
.link { color: navy; }
.username { color: green; }
.hashtag { color: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="myContent">Dear @You, Welcome to @StackOverflow</div>

<div id="myContent2">Hello @World, from @GMKHussain
Trending now! #Hastag

  https://any-domain.net
</div>
```