# How to make editable textarea text non-selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a textarea that is not read-only (users can type), but they cannot select and drag.

All that I found either turns the textarea into readonly, or disables my ability to focus.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: making thing unselectable, a link [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie)

Comment: Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery

Comment: Do you mean you can't click in the corner and drag it to resize? Or do you mean select a word in the text and drag it and drop it into another component?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Answer (score 6):

In jQuery 1.8, this can be done as follows:

```js
$('textarea')
    .attr('unselectable', 'on')
    .css('-webkit-user-select', 'none')
    .css('-moz-user-select', 'none')
    .css("-ms-user-select","none")
    .css("-o-user-select","none")
    .css("user-select",'none')
    .on('selectstart', false)
    .on('mousedown', false);
```

or by just using css,

```css
#yourtextarea
{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems though that when I use this code the entire textarea becomes unselectable (not just the characters) and I can't write inside it anymore. Is it possible to only disable the text selection (the blue part when you select multiple characters)? Thanks!

Comment: @Adam Check [this link](http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/). If you can highlight part of the textarea, you can do something like `onselect`, `unselect` the selected text. Or you can create a new `div` with `contenteditable` set to `true` and then try doing this thing. If not with `textarea` as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873937/how-to-change-a-single-character-color-in-textarea)

Comment: Simplier trick and always working : <div class="wrapper-textarea" style="position: relative"><div class="unselectable" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;"></div><textarea></div> 

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS style `user-select: none;` to keep text from being selectable.

Comment: All it says is `select and drag`. Where does it say resize?

Comment: We'll find out for sure if the OP ever returns to address the comments.

Comment: Yes - I'm back. Thanks for the comments. I meant, to be able to click on a character and then select more and more characters (in such a way that will enable mass-deletions). Thanks.