# how to change the text color after symbol @ like twitter in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I have a textarea which allows user to @ their friends. In order to make it user friendly, I try to change the color after the symbol @ like twitter

```
<textarea id="friend_connect"  title="seperate with space" cols="38" rows="1"  ></textarea>
```

I think what twitter does is to wrap each @username with a span like `<span>@username</span>` and then you are able to style the text color separately.  However, it's definitely not working simply using `<textarea><span>@username</span></textarea>`

I wonder any solutions to fulfill this job

Comment: I have tried <textarea><span>@username</span></textarea>, but it's not working

Comment: Here is a post that may enlighten you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873937/how-to-change-a-single-character-color-in-textarea