# Javascript problems in IE - object expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, wysihat

I'm using a [jQuery fork of Wysihat](https://github.com/swilliams/jq-wysihat) as a Wysiwig editor in a project of mine. It works perfectly in all browsers apart from (surprise, surprise) IE (specifically IE8). I've got the example files uploaded here:

http://pezholio.co.uk/wysihat/examples/custom_buttons.html

When running the file in IE, I get the error `Object expected`, and it seems to be occurring within this function:

```
window.getSelection = (function() {
  var selection = new Selection(document);
  return function() { return selection; };
})();
```

Any ideas what may be causing the problem, and what I can do to fix it?

Cheers

Comment: show function Selection - here is some reading material http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981088/set-textarea-selection-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong in the Wysihat code. `window.Selection` is defined just before that function.

Comment: So, *in IE*, what is the evaluation of `Selection` in that context? And how has that function been pin-pointed? Using the IE Script Debugger?

Comment: Yup, I got at it using the Script debugger. Not sure what you mean about 'what is the evauation of selection in that context'? If you mean the source order, then `Selection` appears before the problematic function. I'm no Javascript ninja by any stretch of the imagination, so would appreciate some help :)

Comment: What is Selection? I've generally used more verbose methods in the past to get txt selections etc.

Comment: This whole function is a mess anyway. If window.getSelection only ever returns the same selection obj, just have it as a property rather than a function. window.currentSelection = newSelection(document);

Comment: There's an IE fallback function for getSelection in there, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried [selection.js](https://github.com/timcameronryan/selection.js) as an alternative, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, OK. I think I've nailed this now. I've removed the existing IE fallback code and am using [selection.js](https://github.com/timcameronryan/selection.js) instead. You can see the code in the gist below:

https://gist.github.com/2556956